# Hashavat Aveda answer

Tags: support

Two minutes ago, I repaired an answer of Shmuel Brin's about a Shut Yaavets concerning having a dog as a pet. I wrote half of the Shut (responsum) which was in a bad, old edition, and I repaired a lack of accuracy in the answer concerning 2 dogs for a man and 1 dog for a woman, the Chashad for woman, even for guarding, and the Moshav letsim for a man if he plays with 1 dog. And when I push "Save" on editing the edit, the screen informed me that this answer was flagged. Is there a possibility to find my edit?

Comment: Please check that my edit matches your intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple ways.

1. Since [you edited from the low-quality review queue](//judaism.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/25845), you can go to [the "history" tab in the low-quality review](//judaism.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) and find your review. [Once there](//judaism.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/25845), you can click the "link" link on the right-hand side to find the post.
2. Since you remember some of the post content, you can search for it by entering search terms in the box atop any page. The post should turn up as [a result](//judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=dog+pet+man+woman).
3. On your own user page, you can go to [the Activity tab](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9215/kouty?tab=topactivity) and thence to the "all actions" sub-tab and the ["reviews"](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9215/kouty?tab=activity&sort=reviews) or ["revisions"](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9215/kouty?tab=activity&sort=revisions) sub-tab, where you can find your most recent reviews or edits.

Comment: This was perfect answer, I used the activity tab in my own user page according to the IIIrd party of the answer.